# Deployment issue in k8s cluster using docker file without minikube, but my is pod not running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, microservices, kubectl

I have created a **k8s [cluster](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-kubernetes-docker-cluster/) by installing "kubelet kubeadm kubectl"**. Now i'm trying to Deploy microservice application as

1. docker build -t demoserver:1.0 .
   =>**image created successfully**
2. kubectl run demoserver --image=demoserver --port=8000 --image-pull-policy=Never
   =>**POD STATUS: ErrImageNeverPull**

I tried " eval $(minikube docker-env)" but it says bash: **minikube: command not found...**

Do i need to install minikube? ***Is my above cluster setup is not enough for deployment??***

Answer (score 1):

Minikube and kubeadm are two unrelated tools. Minikube builds a (usually) single node cluster in a local VM for development and learning. Kubeadm is part of how you install Kubernetes in production environments (sometimes, not all installers use it but it's designed to be a reusable core engine).